# How to show label according to attribute name?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, python-3

I try to show label name according to predefined in QGIS 3.0 by using pyqgis. I used that code in QGIS 3.0 but last update broke it down. Here is my code:

```
    settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    settings.fieldName = 'Subbasin'
    labeling = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(settings)
    wshedLayer.setLabeling(labeling)
    wshedLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: How did it break down? Could you elaborate a bit on that part?

Comment: I mean it does not work. It did not give error but nothing happeneed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this code before `wshedLayer.triggerRepaint()`:

```
wshedLayer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
```

It's all! Thanks to my friend Yusuf Yılmaz.